# Subsurface color disappeared from the Render Layers after Blender upgrade. Does it exist in 2.93?

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers, subsurface-scattering

So I upgraded blender from 2.82 to 2.93, and a render layer called "SubsurfaceCol" has disappeared from the Eevee render layers.
This layer appears when a material with subsurface radios is used in the scene.

[image: a snapshot from compositing] [image]

Was it an experimental feature that got depreciated?
How to bring it back?

Comment: I have checked Blender official manual for you and yes, SubsurfaceCol only appears in versions 2.80 to 2.82, it is removed since version 2.83

Comment: Thank you for checking. I was probably looking in the wrong place for the documentation. The https://docs.blender.org/ doesn't return any search result for the "SubsurfaceCol". Can you give me the correct link, please? I hope to find an alternative.

Comment: At the bottom https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/render/layers/passes.html SubsurfaceCol is short version you need to search for subsurface color in Render layer > passes. I am not sure what is alternative, I am not even sure what this SubsurfaceCol does

Comment: Thank you for the link, MikoCG.
I used SubsurfaceCol as a workaround, but now I switched my solution to Cryptomattes and it's much cleaner.